# Is it possible to access key-value pair from secret manager file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I have a secret manager file in GCP which stores different secrets like db_username,db_password,gcp_project_id etc. The secret file would look something like this

```
db_username=admin
db_password=admin
gcp_project_id= my-project-2345
```

Is it possible to create a single secret with name dev-secret and then access individual key value pair like `dev-secret.db_username` ? I want to have one secret file and it will have multiple config and then access this using CloudRun secrets which will be accessed as an environment variable

Comment: Not directly. Create a JSON or INI file, put your key/values in the file, base64 encode, and store that as a secret. You would then need to base64 decode the secret and process the contents within your app.

Comment: why will i need to encode using base64?

Comment: So that you are storing a **string** value.